# Reports API - Admin Activity – Docs Event Names

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk

In the ADMIN SDK Reports API we can retrieve specific events of admin using statement like:

```
service.activities().list(applicationName="admin",userKey=userEmail,eventName="TRANSFER_DOCUMENT_OWNERSHIP").execute()
```

But Is there facility to generate such admin activity (TRANSFER_DOCUMENT_OWNERSHIP) using the script.????

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking about how to generate a document transfer event? The Reports API is read-only, it's meant to only inform you of actions that took place.

In order to generate a document owner change event, you can either [manually change ownership of a document in the Drive UI](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892?hl=en), or [perform the change of ownership via the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert).

Comment: you understand right, thanks for quick response. I have done it with Drive API. Task completed 90%, the problem I have faced was file which uploaded(extension like .pdf,.csv,.png,.docx) is not transferred.For .docx once I have opened it with Google Docs then it transferred. So anyway for handle such type of case using script.